# Solving simple ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve this ODE:

$$y'(x)=\cos^2(y) \\ y(1)=π$$

$$⇒\int \dfrac{1}{\cos^2(y)} \, dy =\int \, dx $$

$⇒\tan(y) = x +C.$

And $y(1)=π,$ so $\tan(π)=1+C⇔C=-1.$

Now if I solve for $y(x),$

$y(x)=\arctan(\tan(y))=\arctan(x-1)$, which is wrong because $y(1)=π.$

What do I miss when I solve for $y(x)$ in the last step?

The correct answer is $y(x)=\arctan(x-1)+π.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that $\tan y = x+C$ means that $y = \arctan(x+C) + n \pi$ for some integer $n$ (since the tangent function is $\pi$-periodic). You chose the solution with $n=0$, but instead you need to pick another value of $n$ that works better.